# Polyfills not applied to webpack externals

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm working on a project where React and jQuery are being webpacked in as 'externals. Just inserting using  tag method in the head works for most of the project, but I'm still getting errors when firing up IE8 about certain ES5 functions. They're available in the console window, but debug breakpoints show they're not available within React code. [These docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html) hint at a problem toward the bottom - looks like externals are independent of the webpack chain of dependencies. Any thoughts on how to deal with this?

Comment: You could have two outputs with webpack. Output one of just the polyfill setup and another of your actual project. Load the polyfill script before your externals and the rest after.

Comment: Turned out React was being rendered through wicket at an earlier entry point. Found a separate renderHead() in a different file for React. Just inserted my polyfills in that one and it worked.  -- Thanks BenM for the suggestion

Comment: Aha, that could cause it too! No problem.